# Default username and password for H2 database in GeoNetwork

Tags: geonetwork

I know default GeoNetwork installation provides with username: `admin` and password: `admin`, but regarding the database connection settings for the H2 db file, does GeoNetwork use the same ones by default? Or are they stored separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoNetwork uses a default username and password for connecting to the H2 database if you haven't provided any modifying the `jdbc.properties` file of via environment variables.

The [default username and password](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/011cf978963a2d6d0824b56a6b9e53f312a7642e/pom.xml#L1451-L1452) for the H2 database are:

- Username: `www-data`
- Password: `www-data`

You can set your own username and password modifying [`jdbc.properties`](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/011cf978963a2d6d0824b56a6b9e53f312a7642e/web/src/main/webResources/WEB-INF/config-db/jdbc.properties#L24-L25) or defining the `GEONETWORK_DB_USERNAME` and `GEONETWORK_DB_PASSWORD`.